# Using a sky card in Media Center

Tags: windows-media-center, recording, tuner-card

I'm not 100% is this SU suitable but oh well.
I'm wondering if it's possible to get a slot of some kind to put my Sky Card into a Media Center PC and then be able to have a triple or dual tuner, and connect to the satelitte dish, allowing me to record 3 and watch a previously recorded.

Also it would mean access to Youtube and things easily, with only one box.

Also would this be legal or is it similar to Apple where you can only use Mac OSX on boxes with the Apple Logo on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe you're looking for a DVB-S or DVB-S2 PCI card. This should permit you to do what you're trying to do. Whether or not it will work with Windows Media Center is another issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It would be against Sky T&Cs and there are no card readers (Conditional Access Modules)  which work with any reliability for decoding Sky.

To view multiple freesaat channels you would require a multi-out LNB for the satellite dish.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could find a card reader I would imagine that it would be contrary to Sky's terms and conditions.

Don't you need multiple "heads" on the actual satellite dish to be able to view simultaneous channels?

Comment: yes but I'm pretty sure the Sky+ LNB can go up to 4

Comment: No, split the output from the LNB. Power will generally only go via one leg, so make sure the receiver connected to that leg always remains on.

http://www.ehow.com/how_4796572_use-splitter-satellite-tv.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you split the output then there's a problem with changing channels and only being able to watch odd or even channels

Comment: Why when you upgrade to sky+ would the engineer go to all the trouble of drilling another hole through the wall and runnning a second cable to the dish. If splitters could be used then there would be one intergrated into Sky+ boxes, removing the need for 2 cables to the dish.